# send datepart as parameter from a table to DATEADD function in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I Have to Update `City.Date` in City table and I have columns in the table like Interval and Period in the City table.

Interval column contains values like yy,ww,dd,qq,etc and Period column contains values like 1,2,3.

I am trying to update `City.Date` like this:

```
UPDATE City 
SET City.date = DATEADD(City.Interval, City.Period, City.date)
WHERE CityId = 13
```

It is getting error like:

> City.Interval is not recognized DATEADD option.

How can I update `City.Date` using `City.Interval`, `City.Period` and `City.date`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't parameterise the interval bit

```
UPDATE City 
SET date = CASE Interval
              WHEN 'yy' THEN DATEADD(yy, Period, date)
              WHEN 'ww' THEN DATEADD(ww, Period, date)
              WHEN 'dd' THEN DATEADD(dd, Period, date)
              WHEN 'qq' THEN DATEADD(qq, Period, date)
              WHEN ...
           END
WHERE CityId =13
```

Comment: @Avinash: you're welcome. Please vote up and/or accept my answer then (the up and the tick on the left). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I've always been doing Dynamic SQL to make the dateadd function accept a parameter. Well today a different route clicked so I made a function to knock it out for me.

This way I can call it like so

```
declare @datepart_vc varchar(20)
set @datepart_vc = 'day'
select dbo.Dateadd2(@datepart_vc,1,getdate())
```

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateAdd2
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
          @DatePart_VC VARCHAR(20)
        , @Number_IN INT
        , @Date_DT DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Return_DT AS DATETIME

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @Return_DT = (
        CASE 
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'year' THEN DATEADD(year,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'quarter' THEN DATEADD(quarter,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'month' THEN DATEADD(month,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'dayofyear' THEN DATEADD(dayofyear,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'day' THEN DATEADD(day,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'week' THEN DATEADD(week,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'weekday' THEN DATEADD(weekday,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'hour' THEN DATEADD(hour,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'minute' THEN DATEADD(minute,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'second' THEN DATEADD(second,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            --WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'millisecond' THEN DATEADD(millisecond,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            --WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'microsecond' THEN DATEADD(microsecond,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)
            --WHEN @DatePart_VC = 'nanosecond' THEN DATEADD(nanosecond,@Number_IN,@Date_DT)

        END

    )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Return_DT
```

Comment: Is your function declaration missing the END keyword?

Comment: @MartinThurn I do not see an end required in official documentation. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @MartinThurn but this was 7 years ago.. not sure I can recall the intent of this function. It seems redundant with DATEADD and unnecessary. Wish I could remember the intent.