# Pass day/month/year interval via variable to built-in DATEADD function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes, dateadd

I'm trying to use a variable value for the 'interval' in the `DATEADD` built-in function in t-sql. However, this returns an error: 'Invalid parameter 1 specified for dateadd'. Is there a way in t-sql to add this interval input parameter, either via a variable as per the below, or via a table column / temporary table column?

```
DECLARE @start datetime = '20211122',
    @freq int = 7,
    @freqdaypart nvarchar(20) = N'day',
    @now datetime = GETDATE()

;WITH cte(st) AS (
    SELECT @start st
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(@freqdaypart, @freq, st)
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(@freqdaypart, @freq, st) < @now
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

My fallback is to do something like the below but I'd like to avoid this if possible..

```
DECLARE @start datetime = '20211122',
    @freq int = 7,
    @freqdaypart nvarchar(20) = N'day',
    @now datetime = GETDATE()

IF @freqdaypart = 'day'
BEGIN
    ;WITH cte(st) AS (
        SELECT @start st
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @freq, st)
        FROM cte
        WHERE DATEADD(DAY, @freq, st) < @now
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
END

IF @freqdaypart = 'month'
...
```

ps. the above is simplified, in the actual use I intend on retrieving the interval ('day' or 'month') from a database table and process several rows at a time.

Comment: A note from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments): _DATEADD does not accept user-defined variable equivalents for the datepart arguments_.

Comment: This can't be made variable. You need to either settle on a single interval (but that might not be possible for incommensurable quantities like week and month) or else use a `CASE` on `@freqdaypart`, which is less repetition than all the `IF`s but might tank performance if you don't use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

Comment: Side note, a tally would be *significantly* more performance that a rCTE for this kind of task.

Comment: @Zhorov thanks, I could have checked, although I knew that was the cause of the error so I was asking for a different solution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, I am now re-writing this as a `CASE` statement and will probably offer it as a solution if noone else does first. I prefer this to dynamic sql. I've realised the case will need to be on the DATEADD function as the interval parameter doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, by tally do you mean several comma separated CTEs? Please offer as an answer and I will at least +1 it

Comment: [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [send datepart as parameter from a table to DATEADD function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908783/send-datepart-as-parameter-from-a-table-to-dateadd-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a special tip of the hat to Jonathan Roberts of on SQLServerCentral.com, this should do it for you...

```
 CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DateRange 
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a start date, an end date, a "date part", and an increment, return a sequence of rows for the given date part
 according to the dates and the increment.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Parameters:

 @StartDate: Start date of the series    - Required - May be greater than @EndDate 
 @EndDate  : End date of the series      - Required - May be less than @StartDate  
 @DatePart : The time unit for @interval - Optional (Default = 'dd')
     ns    : nanoseconds 
     mcs   : microseconds 
     ms    : milliseconds 
     ss    : seconds
     mi    : minutes
     hh    : hours
     dd    : days
     ww    : weeks
     mm    : months
     qq    : quarters
     yy    : years
 @Interval : The number of dateparts between each value returned - Optional (Default = 1)
------------
     Return: DT as a DATETIME2(7) Column of dates and times
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sample Calls:
--===== Return a row for every other second in the date range.
 SELECT * FROM dbo.DateRange('2011-01-01 12:24:35', '2011-02-01 12:24:35', 'ss', 2)
;
--===== Return a coumt of rows for every millisecond in the date range (Default increment = 1)
     -- A simple DATEDIFF would do the trick but it does demonstate the scope of the function.
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.DateRange('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-25 20:31:23.646', 'ms', default)
;
--===== Return a row for each date in the date range (1st default is "dd" and second default is 1)
 SELECT * FROM dbo.DateRange('2011-01-01', '2012-02-03', default, default)
;
--===== Since @StartDate > @EndDate, this returns a row for every 7 days counting backwards.
 SELECT * FROM dbo.DateRange('2012-02-03', '2011-01-01', 'dd', 7)
;
--===== This demonstrates how you can do calculations in the SELECT list.
 SELECT DATEDIFF(ns,'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',Value),Value,* 
   FROM dbo.DateRange('2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2018-01-01 00:00:00.00001', 'ns', 100)
;
--===== See the following link for an example that seriously simplified the task at hand as well as making it easy to 
     -- add other "granularities" (date parts).
        https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/tsql-create-dynamic-partition-datarange#post-3944333
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 19 Aug 2019 - Jonathan Roberts
        - Initial Release
        - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/a-daterange-table-valued-function

 Rev 01 - 25 Oct 2021 - Jeff Moden.
        - Apply personal code standards and additional information in the documentation
        - Add link to extreme sample usage where the function greatly simplified the task at hand as well as making it
          easy to add other "granularities".
        - Add WITH SCHEMABINDING.
        - Code reduction by moving /@Interval from each THEN to END of CASE.
 *********************************************************************************************************************/  
--===== Function I/O
        (
         @StartDate DATETIME2
        ,@EndDate   DATETIME2
        ,@DatePart  VARCHAR(3) = 'dd'
        ,@Interval  INT        = 1
        )
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
     AS RETURN WITH
--===== 16 digit base for InLine Tally Table
H(Z) AS (SELECT 0 FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))H0(Z)),
--===== InLine Tally Table returns rows starting at 0 based on the DATEPART divided by the interval.
T(N) AS (SELECT TOP(ABS(
                CASE @DatePart
                WHEN 'ns'  THEN DATEDIFF(ns, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'mcs' THEN DATEDIFF(mcs,@EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'ms'  THEN DATEDIFF(ms, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'ss'  THEN DATEDIFF(ss, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'mi'  THEN DATEDIFF(mi, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'hh'  THEN DATEDIFF(hh, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'dd'  THEN DATEDIFF(dd, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'ww'  THEN DATEDIFF(ww, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'mm'  THEN DATEDIFF(mm, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'qq'  THEN DATEDIFF(qq, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'yy'  THEN DATEDIFF(yy, @EndDate,@StartDate)
                ELSE DATEDIFF(dd --Ensures we get a correct positive value if dates are reversed
                             ,IIF(@StartDate < @EndDate, @StartDate, @EndDate)
                             ,IIF(@StartDate < @EndDate, @EndDate, @StartDate)
                             )
                END/@Interval) + 1) --End of TOP(ABS, Adds 1 interval to makeup for subtraction of INTs
            N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 --So we start at ZERO
           FROM H a,H b,H c,H d,H e,H f,H g,H h -- A maximum of 16^8 (or 2^32) rows can be returned
        )
         SELECT DT = 
                CASE @DatePart            
                WHEN 'ns'  THEN DATEADD(ns, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'mcs' THEN DATEADD(mcs,c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'ms'  THEN DATEADD(ms, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'ss'  THEN DATEADD(ss, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'mi'  THEN DATEADD(mi, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'hh'  THEN DATEADD(hh, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'dd'  THEN DATEADD(dd, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'ww'  THEN DATEADD(ww, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'mm'  THEN DATEADD(mm, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'qq'  THEN DATEADD(qq, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                WHEN 'yy'  THEN DATEADD(yy, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                ELSE            DATEADD(dd, c.CountAmount,@StartDate)
                END 
           FROM T t
          CROSS APPLY(VALUES(IIF(@StartDate<@EndDate
                                ,@Interval*(t.N)  --Count Up
                                ,@Interval*(-t.N) --Count Down
                                )))c(CountAmount)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL, something like this

```
DECLARE @sqlToExecute NVARCHAR(4000);

DECLARE @start datetime = '20211122',
    @freq int = 7,
    @freqdaypart nvarchar(20) = N'day',
    @now datetime = GETDATE()

SET @sqlToExecute = N'

;WITH cte(st) AS (
    SELECT @start st
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(' + @freqdaypart + ', @freq, st)
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(' + @freqdaypart + ', @freq, st) < @now
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlToExecute, 
    N'@start DATETIME, 
    @freq INT, 
    @now DATETIME
    ', @start, @freq, @now
```

Comment: I strongly suggest validating the input value of `@freqdaypart`; otherwise this is an injection issue.

Comment: Yes agree, but his code it was hard coded so knew that case was safe, depends where he ends up putting that logic, if passing in to the store proc then yes.

Comment: If the value was hardcoded, they wouldn't be asking the question; as then they would just hardcode the value in `DATEADD`.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, I have upvoted it as that is a valid solution. I'd prefer to avoid dynamic sql though and will likely write an answer using a `CASE` statement as suggested in a different comment.

Comment: Use statement terminators consistently and you don't need the "beginator" kludge for lazy coders. You don't need it AT ALL in this example.

Comment: Can you elaborate more @SMor?

Comment: @Andrew `;WITH` the semi-colon is part of the preceding statement. If you terminate *all* statements with `;` then this is not necessary. Pedantic, but....

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Charlieface, yes, like many I don't use them all over the place.